# Javascript includes required for using prometheus graph library

Tags: prometheus

1. If I have to use the Graph Library described at https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/consoles/#graph-library in my web app, what are the JavaScript/CSS files I should include?
2. I understand the above graph library makes an API call to Prometheus at /api/v1/query_range - is there a way to add a prefix to this URL so that I can proxy it via my app's endpoint on the server?
3. How do I "try out" the console example at /consoles/index.html.example? If I rename this to /consoles/index.html, how/where do I see in the prometheus  expression browser app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `prom_console.js` and `prom_console.css`.

There is a variable called `PATH_PREFIX` you need to set, which you can do this with.

It'll be on http://localhost:9090/consoles/index.html.example